# Dynamic database design for variable length spatio-temporal data in Oracle (need a schema design)

Tags: oracle, database-design, data-modeling, spatial

Currently I am working on a research project, where I need to store spatio-temporal data and analyze them efficiently. I am giving the exact requirement below.

The research is going on meteorological data, so the data attributes are temperature, humidity, pressure, wind-speed, wind-direction etc. The number of attributes is previously unknown to us, depending on requirement we may need to add more attributes (Table having dynamic attribute and different datatype nature). Again the data is captured from various locations, from various height and in a certain time duration as well as time interval.

So, what should be the best way to design a schema for the requirement? We must have to find out relation efficiently.

The purpose of the project is not only to store database, also need to manipulate the data.

**Sample data in table format -**

```
location | time                | height | pressure | temperature | wind-direction | ...
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | 7      | 1009.6   | 28.3        | east           | ...
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | 15     | 1008.6   | 27.9        | east           | ...
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | 27     | 1007.4   | 27.4        | east           | ...
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:04 | 7      | 1010.2   | 28.4        | north-east     | ...
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:04 | 15     | 1009.4   | 28.2        | north-east     | ...
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:04 | 27     | 1008.9   | 27.6        | north-east     | ...
L2       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | ..... so on
```

Here I need to design a schema for the above sample data where Location is a spatial location that can be implemented using oracle MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY type.

Constraints are:

1. The no of attributes (table column) is unknown during development. In runtime any new attribute(let say - humidity, refractive index etc.) can be added. So we can't design attribute specific table schema.
       1.1) for this constraint I thought to use a schema like -
              *tbl_attributes(attr_id_pk, attr_name, attr_type);
             
   tbl_data(loc, time, attr_id_fk, value);*
        The my design the attribute value must be varchar type, and as required I thought to cast (not a good idea at all).
        But finding relational data with this schema is very difficult using SQL query only. For example I want to find - 
             1.1.1) avg pressure for location L1 when wind direction is east and temperature in between 27-28
            1.1.2) locations, where pressure is maximum at 15 height.
        1.2) I am also thinking to edit table schema during runtime, which is again not a good idea I think.
2. We will use a loader application, which will be taking care of this dynamic insertion depending on the schema (what ever it maybe).
3. Need to retrieve statistical data efficiently as some example is given above [1.1.*].

Comment: the information you give is not enough... what have tried ? what do you mean by "manipulate the data" exactly ?

Comment: First I need to design a schema, so that I can store the data, when the no of attributes is unknown previously.

second, the schema should be well enough, so that query must be efficient enough.

Comment: None of what you desrribe helps in answering your question... it is just too general for a question on SO.

Comment: OK, let me describe with an example

Comment: <b>The view gives very bad performance, even when I have implemented index, partition on metfeatures table. So, I am going for a runtime schema editing mechanism. </b>

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure I understand what you mean when you say that

> The no of attributes (table column) is unknown during development. In
>   runtime any new attribute(let say - humidity, refractive index etc)
>   can be added.

first of all, I suppose that this is not really happening at random: i.e. when you get a new bunch of data from the field you know (before importing) that these have an extra dimension or two. Correct?

Also, the fact that in this new data batch you get "refractive index" will not make the older data magically acquire a proper value for this dimension.

Therefore I would go for a classical Object-to-RDBMS mapping where you have:

a header table with things that exist for every measurement: i.e. time and space, possibly the source (i.e. lab, sensor, team which provided the data) and an autogenerated key.

one or more detail table where the values are defined as proper fields.

Example:

Header

```
location | time                | height | source  |Key          | 
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | 7      | team-1  | 002020013   | 
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | 15     | team-1  | 002020017   | 
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:02 | 27     | Lab-X   | 002020018   | 
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:04 | 7      | Lab-Y   | 002020021   | 
L1       | 2011-12-18 08:04:04 | 15     | Lab-X   | 002020112   |
```

Atmospheric data (basic)

```
Key       | pressure  | temp | wind-dir  | 
002020013 | 1009.6    | 28.3 | east      |
002020017 | 1019.3    | 29.2 | east      |
002020018 | 1011.6    | 26.9 | east      |
```

Light-sensor data

```
Key       | refractive-ind  | albedo  | Ultraviolet  |
002020017 |         79.6    | .37865  | 7.0E-34      |
002020018 |         67.4    | .85955  | 6.5E-34      |
002020021 |         91.6    | .98494  | 8.1E-34      |
```

In other words: every different set of data will use one or more subtables (these you can add "dynamically", if needed) and you can still create queries by standard means, you will just have to join subtables (where possible: i.e. if you want to analyze by Wind Directions AND refractive index, you can - but only when you have set of data which have both values) by using the reference keys to keep these consistent).

I believe this more efficient than using text fields with CSV inside, or data blobs or using a key-values associations.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with 1.2 (edit table schema during runtime), at least to begin with.  Any sufficiently advanced configuration is indistinguishable from programming; don't think you can magically avoid making changes to your program.

Don't be scared of `alter table`.  Yes, the upfront costs are higher - you may need a process (not just a program) to ensure your schema stays clean.  And there are some potential locking problems (that have solutions).  **But if you do it right you only have to pay the price once for each change.**

With a completely generic solution you will pay a small price with every query.  Your queries will be complicated, slower, ugly, and more likely to fail.  You can never write a query like `select avg(value) ...`, it may or may not work, depending on how the data is accessed.  You can use a PL/SQL function to catch exceptions, or use inline views and hints to force a specific access pattern.  Either way, your queries are more complicated and slower, and you have to make sure that everybody understands these problems before they use the data.

And with a generic solution the optimizer will suck because it knows nothing about your data.  Oracle can't predict how many rows will be returned by `where attr_name = 'temperature' and is_number(value) = 28.4`.  But it can make a very good guess for `where temperature = 28.4`.  You may have significantly more bad plans (i.e. slow queries) with generic columns.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the quick response and good guidance. I have gotten some concepts from the both answers and decided to go with a mix model. I don't know whether I am in the write path or not. I want comments on the model. Below I am describing the complete conceptual model with MySQL code snippet.

### Conceptual model

1. **For dynamicity**  - (no of column is not defined previously) I have created 4 tables as follows -

   - ***geolocation(locid int, name varchar, geometry spatial_type)*** - to store information of a particular location, may be defined with spatial feature.
   - ***met_loc_event(loceventid int, locid* int, record_time timestamp, height float)*** - this is to identify a perticular event in a place with sudden height.
   - ***metfeatures(featureid int, name varchar, type varchar)*** - to store feature (ie. Column) details with a data type, that type field will help to cast data as required.
   - ***metstore(loceventid* int, featureid* int, value varchar)*** - to store an atom value for a feature at a particular time.
     Up to that part I design a column orientation to store a dynamic nature of table. But as you suggest this is not a good design for quering (some will not work like arithmetic functions) the database. This is also not good if we consider performance.
2. **For efficient query needs**  (to avoid to much joining and to avoid casting value during query) - I extend the model with some helper view, I write store procedure to generate views from the stored database.

   - First I created views for each feature (by taking value from feature table, so no of entry will be no of feature view initially) with the help of met_loc_event, metfeatures and metstore tables. These views store ***locid, record_time, height, and caste value** according to feature type*
   - Next from these views, I created a **row oriented view** named metrelview - which consist of all relation data row wise as like normal table. I have planned to fire query to the view, so the query performance will be improved.
   - This view generation procedure needs to execute whenever any insert, update or delete operation will be there in features table.

### Below is the MySQL procedure that I have developed for the view generation

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `buildModel`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE fid INTEGER;
    DECLARE fname VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE ftype VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE cur_fatures CURSOR FOR SELECT `featureid`, `name`, `type` FROM `metfeatures`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    SET @viewAlias = 'v_';
    SET @metRelView = "metrelview";
    SET @stmtCols = "";
    SET @stmtJoin = "";

    START TRANSACTION;

    OPEN cur_fatures;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur_fatures INTO fid, fname, ftype;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        IF fname IS NOT NULL THEN
            SET @featureView = CONCAT(@viewAlias, LOWER(fname));
            IF ftype = 'float' THEN
                SET @featureCastStr = "`value`+0.0";
            ELSEIF ftype = 'int' THEN
                SET @featureCastStr = "CAST(`value` AS SIGNED)";
            ELSE
                SET @featureCastStr = "`value`";
            END IF;

            SET @stmtDeleteView = CONCAT("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `", @featureView, "`");
            SET @stmtCreateView = CONCAT("CREATE VIEW `", @featureView, "` AS SELECT le.`loceventid` AS loceventid, le.`locid`, le.`rectime`, le.`height`, ", @featureCastStr, " AS value FROM `metlocevent` le JOIN `metstore` ms ON (le.`loceventid`=ms.`loceventid`) WHERE ms.`featureid`=", fid);
            PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtDeleteView;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtCreateView;
            EXECUTE stmt;

            SET @stmtCols = CONCAT(@stmtCols, ", ", @featureView, ".`value` AS ", @featureView);
            SET @stmtJoin = CONCAT(@stmtJoin, " ", "LEFT JOIN ", @featureView, " ON (le.`loceventid`=", @featureView,".`loceventid`)");
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    SET @stmtDeleteView = CONCAT("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `", @metRelView, "`");
    SET @stmtCreateView = CONCAT("CREATE VIEW `", @metRelView, "` AS SELECT le.`loceventid`, le.`locid`, le.`rectime`, le.`height`", @stmtCols, " FROM `metlocevent` le", @stmtJoin);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtDeleteView;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtCreateView;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    CLOSE cur_fatures;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

***N.B. - I tried to call the procedure with any event in features table, so that every thing should be automated. But as MySQL is not supported dynamic query with function or trigger, I cant do it automatically***
**I also want criticism before i finalize as accepted model, I am not a DBA so, if you can help me how to improve performance for the model will be very helpful for me.**

Comment: If you're using MySQL instead of Oracle you should edit the tags on the question.  I'm not familiar with MySQL and some of my advice probably doesn't apply.

Comment: Sagar, I have real doubts about the need of having "dynamic" structures like your "metfeatures" table. Of course I don't know your exact requirements, but in my experience this kind of "flexibility" gives very poor performance and it's almost never needed. The day your system needs to take care of a completely new sensor or measure you will have to make changes in various parts of the system (the data import, for example) so that would be the right time to add a well-specified subtable, instead of a bunch of disconnected fields. No disrespect here, just a word of caution.

Comment: To jonearles, finally I need to implement this concept in oracle, but as in my personal system MySQL is already installed, I just make a quick implementation to make sure whether this concept is possibly working or not and seems working. Yet I am not sure about performance.

Comment: To p.marino, I am also supporting your experience and suggestions to not to implement dynamic structure due to performance issue. But as our requirement, we have to develop a research tool on meteorology, where features can be added, modified as required. Yes, it is good idea to add column manually as required. Here the problem is the expert domain users are not computer programmer, they wants flexible, configurable tool. As I also scared about the performance I asked the topic to the experts here.

Comment: To solve the dynamic issue, I combine both concept as suggested by you and by jonearles, I first store the values in a single column, then when ever a new feature will arrived, or modified, I created a view which is exactly same as the relational view (as my first example), so you can think instead of manually, I added the column at the run time. Hence The no of join will also be avoided as a single view contains all relation structure.

If you still think this is a problem, please inform me.

Comment: Sagar... have you looked into so-called NoSQL systems for this? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) - personally I don't have any direct experience so I cannot be sure that they would solve your problems, but from what I read so far they may provide a good alternative when you have somehow "unstructured" data schemas.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework assignment whose underlying subject is: use-cases for abandoning strict normal-form design principles.

The solution to this conundrum is to develop a three-stage solution.  Stage 1 is runtime adaptability using the flexible AttributeType, AttributeValue approach, so that rapidly incoming data can be captured and put somewhere temporarily in a quasi-structured manner. Stage 2 involves the analysis of that runtime data to see where the model must be extended with additional columns and validation tables to accommodate any new attributes. Stage 3 is the importing of the as-yet-unimported data into the revised model, which never relaxes its strict datatyping and declarative referential integrity constraints.

As they say: Life, friends, is a trade-off.